# Using google map in an android application

Tags: android

i developed an app that allow a user to write a location name in an edittext,then the location displayed on google map.i also want the app to joint the distance between the current location and the search location and tell the user the distance in meter between the two location and also trace the user to the search location.

Comment: It's like you are asking us to write your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

-> For Serching the location and show on map ,you can check this [link1](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/)

-> For getting distance between two locations you can check this [link2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

->For tracing the user to the searched location , you can show the route between both location, which is already done in [link2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/).